# Trying to open .bson file and read to pandas df but getting 'bson.errors.InvalidBSON: objsize too large' first time using .bson

Tags: python, pandas, bson

#This is my code

```
import pandas as pd
import bson

FILE="users_(1).bson"

with open(FILE,'rb') as f:
    data = bson.decode_all(f.read())

main_df=pd.DataFrame(data)
main_df.describe()
```

#This is my .bson file

```
[{'_id': ObjectId('999f24f260f653401b'),
    'isV2': False,
    'isBeingMigratedToV2': False,
    'firstName': 'Jezz',
    'lastName': 'Bezos',
    'subscription': {'_id': ObjectId('999f24f260f653401b'),
     'chargebeeId': 'AzZdd6T847kHQ',
     'currencyCode': 'EUR',
     'customerId': 'AzZdd6T847kHQ',
     'nextBillingAt': datetime.datetime(2022, 7, 7, 10, 14, 6),
     'numberOfMonthsPaid': 1,
     'planId': 'booster-v3-eur',
     'startedAt': datetime.datetime(2022, 6, 7, 10, 14, 6),
     'addons': [],
     'campaign': None,
     'maskedCardNumber': '************1234'},
    'email': 'jeffbezos@gmail.com',
    'groupName': None,
    'username': 'jeffbezy',
    'country': 'DE'},
   {'_id': ObjectId('999f242660f653401b'),
    'isV2': False,
    'isBeingMigratedToV2': False,
    'firstName': 'Caterina',
    'lastName': 'Fake',
    'subscription': {'_id': ObjectId('999f242660f653401b'),
     'chargebeeId': '16CGLYT846t99',
     'currencyCode': 'GBP',
     'customerId': '16CGLYT846t99',
     'nextBillingAt': datetime.datetime(2022, 7, 7, 10, 10, 41),
     'numberOfMonthsPaid': 1,
     'planId': 'personal-v3-gbp',
     'startedAt': datetime.datetime(2022, 6, 7, 10, 10, 41),
     'addons': [],
     'campaign': None,
     'maskedCardNumber': '************4311'},
    'email': 'caty.fake@gmail.com',
    'groupName': None,
    'username': 'cfake',
    'country': 'GB'}]
```

I get the error

```
'bson.errors.InvalidBSON: objsize too large'
```

Is it something to do with the datetime? Is it the structure of the .bson file, been at this for hours and can't seem to see the error. I know how to work with json and tried to convert it to json but no success. Any tips would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the main goal here is to read the data into a pandas DataFrame you could indeed format the data to json and use [`bson.json_util.loads`](https://dfproj.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api/bson/json_util.html):

```
import pandas as pd
from bson.json_util import loads

with open(filepath,'r') as f:
    data = f.read()

mapper = {
    '\'': '"',   # using double quotes
    'False': 'false',
    'None': '\"None\"',  # double quotes around None
    # modifying the ObjectIds and timestamps
    '("': '(', 
    '")': ')', 
    ')': ')"',
    'ObjectId': '"ObjectId',
    'datetime.datetime': '"datetime.datetime'
}
for k, v in mapper.items():
    data = data.replace(k, v)

data = loads(data)
df = pd.DataFrame(data)
```